# Adding unknown amount of objects to Array via function

Tags: php, arrays, function

So, first off. I'm a C# programmer, so my PHP code is probably strongly influenced by how you would write in C#.  Anyway, I'm trying to solve a problem where I've got a two-dimensional grid with two axis, x and y. The user gives input, and the program will tell you your new location.

For example, if user input was ' >^ ' the location would be 1,1.
What I also want the program to do, is to tell you the first location that you revisit. So, if you go from 0,0 -> 0,1 -> 0,0 -> 1,0 -> 1,1. Then the first location you revisited was 0,0.
My problem is that I'm trying to send my int to a function and then adding it to an array, and searching the array if the array contains the object. But it seems like the array is only adding one value (?)

```
declare(strict_types=1);
<?php

$NewInput = ">>^^<>>";
$arr = str_split($NewInput, 1);
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
Directions($x, $y, $arr);
function Directions (int $x, int $y, $arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $item)
    {
        if ($item == '^')
        {
            $y += 1;
        }
        elseif ($item == 'v')
        {
            $y -= 1;
        }
        elseif ($item == '>')
        {
            $x += 1;
        }
        elseif ($item == '<')
        {
            $x -= 1;
        }
        Previous($x,$y);
    }
}
function Previous (string $x, string $y)
{
    $Location = $x . '.' . $y;
    echo "<br>";
    $NewArray = array();
    $NewArray[] = $Location;
    $ReVisited = "";
    if ($ReVisited == "")
    {
       if (array_search($Location, $NewArray))
        {
            $ReVisited = $Location;
            echo $ReVisited;
        }
    }
    echo $Location;
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?
And also if you see something overall with the code that could be improved please let me know.
Grateful for any tips or answers!

Comment: Can you please extract and provide a [mcve]? Also, at what point exactly does the program not behave  as expected? And what did you expect instead? As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. As new PHP programmer, check out the PSR documents, in particular the coding guidelines concerning naming and formatting. You'll have an easier time cooperating with others.

Comment: My bad. Thankfully I got help without the roasting for my bad question. Will construct my questions in the future more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with the other answer: The key reason your code isn't working is because you are re-initialising `$newArray` every time you call the function `Previous()` and hence the array is `null`.

To get around this you could use `global` as @Andrew suggested.

However, your code seems a little unorganised and overly complicated... There doesn't seem to be any need for two separate functions? The whole process is effectively one function.

If you treat it as one function then you have no need of using `globals` and you can do it in far fewer lines of code!

```
$NewInput    = ">>^^<>>";
$arr         = str_split($NewInput, 1);
$x           = 0;
$y           = 0;

directions($x, $y, $arr);

function directions($x, $y, $arr){
    $used_points = []; // Array of points which have been passed through
    $repeats     = []; // Array of points which have been repeated
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        switch ($item) {
            case '^':
                $y += 1;
                break;
            case 'v':
                $y -= 1;
                break;
            case '>':
                $x += 1;
                break;
            case '<':
                $x -= 1;
                break;
        }

        $current_point = "{$x}.{$y}";
        $repeat        = in_array($current_point, $used_points); // Checks if the point is repeated
        echo $current_point . (($repeat) ? " REPEAT\n" : "\n");  // Outputs current point and whether it's a repeat

        $used_points[] = $current_point; // Add current point to $used_points array
    }
}

/*  Output:
        1.0
        2.0
        2.1
        2.2
        1.2
        2.2 REPEAT
        3.2
*/
```

### Additional Explanation

#### SWITCH

The `switch` statement is effectively just another way of writing your `if...elseif` statements in a way which is easier to read. Functionally it does the same job (i.e. comparing a given value against another).

The three code examples below show different ways of comparing the values. The third example is effectively what a `switch` statement is.

N.B. `break` is required in the `switch` and `while` statements to exit the statement. If you omit it then the code continues to run further down the page than you may have intended.

```
## Example code with switch
switch ($test_case){
    case 1:
        // Do something if $test_case == 1...
        break;
    case 2:
        // Do something if $test_case == 2...
        break;
}

## Example code with if/elseif
if($test_case == 1){
    // Do something if $test_case == 1...
}
elseif($test_case == 2){
    // Do something if $test_case == 2...
}

## Example of if statements in a loop equivalent to switch
while(TRUE){
    if($test_case == 1){
        // Do something if $test_case == 1...
        break;
    }
    if($test_case == 2){
        // Do something if $test_case == 2...
        break;
    }
    break;
}
```

#### { curly braces } and double quotes

You can reference variables directly inside of double quotes; this often times makes code easier to read and nicer to look at. Example:

```
echo $a . ", " . $b . ", " . $c . ", " $d;
echo "$a, $b, $c, $d";
```

There are however instances when doing the above can give unexpected results. The curly braces help to keep that to a minimum and is just a good practice to get into - they clearly specify which variable you mean to reference.

```
$current_point = "$x.$y"; // is equivalent to....
$current_point = "{$x}.{$y}";
```

#### in_array($needle, $haystack)

`in_array` is simply a way to check whether or not a value is present in an array. If the value is found then the function returns `TRUE` if not then `FALSE`.

The line...

```
$repeat = in_array($current_point, $used_points);
```

...therefore sets `$repeat` to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

#### Ternary Operator

The ternary operator is effectively a short hand `if...else` statement.

```
## Example of if/else
$output = "";
if($value == TRUE){
    $output = 1;
}
else{
    $output = 2;
}

## Example with ternary operator
$output = ($value) ? 1 : 2;
```

In your case we use it to check if `$repeat` is `TRUE` (i.e. the current coordinate is present in the already visited coordinates array). If it is `TRUE` then we output  `REPEAT\n` or `\n` by itself if it isn't.

```
echo ($repeat) ? " REPEAT\n" : "\n";
```

The whole line...

```
echo $current_point . (($repeat) ? " REPEAT\n" : "\n");
```

...then outputs the `$current_point` followed by either  `REPEAT\n` or `\n`.

Comment: This is a much better and more complete answer, with way sexier code. Cheers!

Comment: This code is great. Works wonders! The biggest issue for me is that I'm having a hard time truly understand what everything in the code does.

Comment: I have added further explanations for some of the points that are commonly troublesome... Hopefully this clears things up!

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! Thank you so much. That cleared up 99% of the things I didn't understand. 
You're a star!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% if I understand correctly your desired outcome, but here are the problems I see:
You keep redefining $NewArray in the Previous function, so every time you run it, the array will become empty. You have to put that variable outside the function, and refer to it with the [global](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) scope. I also renamed it to $previousLocations. Here is the new function:

```
$previousLocations = array();
function Previous (string $x, string $y)
{
    global $previousLocations;
    $Location = $x . '.' . $y;
    echo "<br>";
    if(in_array($Location, $previousLocations)) {
      // Already visited location
      echo "Revisiting: " . $Location;
    } else {
      $previousLocations[] = $Location;
      echo $Location;
    }
}
```

Output:
1.0
2.0
2.1
2.2
1.2
Revisiting: 2.2
3.2

Please correct me if I misunderstood something.

Comment: That was a miss on my part, redefining the array every time. 
You understood correctly, my bad that I explained it badly. Anyhow, when I try your code, it never comes out as true, only false. So even though i have locations that already have been visited, it doesn't write it out.

Comment: That's odd, it seems to be working in the demo here: https://3v4l.org/rF67d    (I also fixed a warning about the array not being defined on the first check)

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing... I had written $PreviousLocation instead of $previousLocation. So a capital P was the issue. I'm so used to getting error messages for simple misses like that. 
Changed that and now It works! Thank you for your help!.